# How to delete a row from UITableView with RxSwift without any inconsistency error?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, rx-swift

```
todoTableView.rx.itemDeleted.asObservable()
    .subscribe({ (event) in
        let indexpath = event.element
            self.viewModel.deleteToDo(index: (indexpath?.row)!, completion: {
                self.todoTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexpath!], with: .fade)
            })
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

when I delete a row from tableView, The table gets updated before the delete animation occurs, due to which i am receiving an internal inconsistency error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete it in the data source the table is subscribed to. Then it is automatically propagated to the table. I.e. *not* via `deleteRows` method.

Comment: Thanks....i did that and I am not receiving any inconsistency error but the problem is now i cannot see the delete animation. When i swipe to delete and click on the delete button, it is just stuck there and when i touch somewhere else...the table is updated. I am not receiving any error but facing this issue.

Comment: Are you using `RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource`?

Comment: well you should if you need animation